# Which IRS address to choose for federal tax return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs

Do you choose the IRS address for submitting your federal taxes based on where you currently live (the return address on the envelope) or where your current resident was in that tax year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the address based on where you currently live (where you are mailing the tax return from.)

You can find the [correct mailing address here](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Where-To-File-Addresses-for-Tax-Professionals). Just choose the state you live in, and the website will give you the correct mailing address.

If you get it wrong, I don't think it matters a whole lot, except perhaps to delay things a little bit. They just assign different addresses to different states to try to divide up the returns among the various offices evenly.

Answer (score 2):

The one where you want to receive correspondence from the IRS.

Comment: For _IRS_ purposes, does it matter what return address is on the _envelope_ that contains the tax return? Wouldn't the IRS just send any correspondence to the address shown on the _return_ itself? (I know the return address on the envelope matters for _USPS_ purposes if the Post Office wants to return the envelope to the sender because it is not deliverable as addressed, or the sender did not put on enough stamps, etc).

Comment: @DilipSarwate the IRS will send correspondence to the address on the latest return, the address on the envelope is of no significance for that purpose. I understood the OP to be asking about the address on the return, not the envelope.

Comment: Well, he did specifically say "where you currently live (the return address on the envelope)" instead of address on the return, and so I suppose I interpreted his statement more literally than you did.